# How to send an email without using a ViewController?

Tags: ios, email

I want to make an app that automatically emails me information put into text fields. I do not want the ViewController to pop up - I just want them to click send and it automatically sends to me. How might I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see two possible solutions to this problem.

1. Set up a server and send your content via HTTP POST to it. Let the server generate and send the email to you. This could be easily implemented with a simple PHP script for instance.
2. Send the email from the device via SMTP yourself. Check out the [`SKPSMPTMessage`](http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/) library.

With that being said, be careful what you send. Don't send user specific information without them knowing and accepting.